# external, and globals in sapper client build using rollup

Tags: svelte, rollupjs, sapper

Building using `rollup` supports externals and globals.

We can import a module in code, and say it as external, then `rollup` doesn't include it in bundle.

If we give global to it, it 'sets' that import resultant to global in `umd` bundle.

But doing same thing using when using `sapper`keeps module as external, then server build working normally, but client build isn't considering globals, but trying to do 'import' in browser, and is failing, with TypeError ,

> ': Failed to resolve module specifier “…”' .

Is it possible to keep a library as external in `sapper` client build, and direct it to use global instead of importing ? Or i am getting some very fundamentals wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you keep a module external to the bundle, what that actually means is that the `import` declaration is preserved in the generated code. So if you have something like

```js
import foo from 'foo';
```

then your server code will have something like

```js
const foo = require('foo');
```

(which works, because of the Node module resolution algorithm), and in your client JS you'll end up with the exact same `import`... which *doesn't* work in browsers, because import paths need to be relative. (This may change in future with import maps.)

The easiest solution is not to use `external`, and just let Rollup handle it (you could do this just for the client). But if you did want to use a global instead, you could perhaps use [`@rollup/plugin-virtual`](https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/virtual):

```js
plugins: [
  virtual({
    foo: `export default window.foo`
  }),
  // ...
]
```

and then add a `<script>` tag in your `src/template.html` that pointed to a file in `static`.